# namecoin name_firstupdate

Tags: json-rpc, namecoin, php

Hey I am trying to connect to my namecoin server. I have hosted and done the first *name_firstupdate*. I am using easybitcoin.php. I have stored the *rnd* and *txid* I need from the *name_new* step but when I execute the code the server doesn't respond with anything. I checked my namecoind *name_list* the domain that's being registered doesn't show up. Any help would be awesome, thank you.

http://allaboutbit.com/dotbitaddress for an example of the prior steps.

```
$d = 'd/';
$space = " ";
require_once('easybitcoin.php');
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin('username','password','159.206.21.47','8336');
$domainQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT domain_name from dotbitdomains WHERE status = '13'");
$domainLevel = mysqli_fetch_row($domainQuery);
            $url = $domainLevel[0];
//select rnd
$rndQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT rnd from dotbitdomains WHERE status = '13'");
$rndLevel = mysqli_fetch_row($rndQuery);
            $rnd = $rndLevel[0];
//select txid
$txidQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT txid from dotbitdomains WHERE status = '13'");
$txidLevel = mysqli_fetch_row($txidQuery);
            $txid = $txidLevel[0];
//select username
$userQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username from dotbitdomains WHERE status = '13'");
$userLevel = mysqli_fetch_row($userQuery);
            $username = $userLevel[0];
$bitcoin->name_firstupdate($d.$url.$space.$rnd.$space.$txid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you didn't provide enough information:

- Which OS?
- Version number of your Namecoin server?
- Does this Namecoin server run on your local machine? If not, how is it connected physically?
- Did you apply any command line params when starting the server?
- What is the content of your namecoin.conf file?

Generally speaking, the most common causes for RPC connection problems are:

- Mismatch of the provided data (rpcuser, rpcpassword, rpcport) with the contents of namecoin.conf
- Command line parameter *-server* is missing